# _csrf token is spring 3.2.8

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I want to protect my application from CSRF attacks, so I added this to my applicationContext.xml:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

        <security:http auto-config="true">
            <security:csrf/>    
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"    />
        </security:http>

<security:authentication-manager/>
```

this to my web.xml

```
<!-- spring security csrf -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>fr.telecom.support.context.DevicesSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>    
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

and this my filter

```
public class DevicesSecurityFilter extends DelegatingFilterProxy {

    public DevicesSecurityFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(Filter delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(String targetBeanName) {
        super(targetBeanName);
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(String targetBeanName,
            WebApplicationContext wac) {
        super(targetBeanName, wac);
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
        ThreadContext threadContext;

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            threadContext = ThreadContext.getInstance();

            try {
                EcasUser ecasUser = (EcasUser) httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
                if (ecasUser != null) {
                    threadContext.setDomainUsername(ecasUser.getDomainUsername());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            threadContext.setUserID(httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser());
        }

        System.out.println ("filterChain -> " + filterChain );  

        if (filterChain != null) {

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        }
    }
```

and in the JSP I added

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

But when I run the program and ckech the JSP this is what I found !  and no exception is thrown !

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
```

I guess something like this should appear:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="8d0bf854-83a1-4fbf-a792-390a84ecf545"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would say that extending `DelegatingFilterProxy` is not a very good idea.

Problem is that the delegate never is invoked.

A possible quickfix would be to replace `filterChain.doFilter` with:

```java
super.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
```